# Why spring-data-gemfire reposories do not use putAll?

Tags: spring-data, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I noticed that spring-data-gemfire repositories are extremely slow in client-server architecture when it comes to uploading a big data set into gemfire cache.
I checked the sources and I see that

```
save(Iterable<U> entities)
```

just iterates through all the entries and puts them individually.

Why doesn't it use Region.putAll? - it would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you are correct.  This predates me, but I will implement this change.  See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-343 for further details.

We do have 1 more scheduled 1.4 SDG release (1.4.5 for SR5) in Spring Data Dijkstra release train (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Dijkstra).  This change will also be targeted at the SDG 1.5.1 (Evans SR1) release and will obviously be included in the upcoming 1.6 M1 (Fowler) release.

If you are not using 1 of these SDG versions, then I encourage you to upgrade as I will not back port this change to 1.3.x or earlier.

Cheers!

Comment: The change is complete!